# What are these devices outside my patio door?

Tags: electrical

I have these two devices outside my patio door and I have no idea what they are or what they are used for. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: How long have you lived there? Have you ever had to let a meter reader into the house?

Comment: I've been in this house for about 8 months. I have not had to let a meter reader into the house.

Comment: the one on the right looks like a sonic pest repeller.

Comment: Looks like the previous owner was a big fan of monitoring weather :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one on the left is a remote thermohydrometer. It reads the air temperature and humidity and transmits the data to a weather station.

The one on the right could be a similar device, or else a short-range transmitter that repeats one of your utility meters so the meter man can read it from his van as he drives by.

You should do a network search (eg Google) for the words written on the device.

Comment: Or post a picture where the words are readable -- I'm curious now.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The first one makes sense (except I don't have a weather station). The second one doesn't make sense as it is on the wrong side of the house and about 100 ft from the nearest road. I wasn't able to read the lettering on the smaller one.

Comment: I'll try to get a better picture but I won't be able to post until tomorrow. Also, there is at least one other small one on the same side of the house as these two. It is high up on the second floor though.

Comment: @Hooplehead24 product link to [TX8U
Wireless Temperature & Humidity Sensor](https://www.lacrossetechnology.com/tx8/index.php)

Comment: Wow, nice. Yup that's the one. Now I just need the other one.

Comment: I posted a new picture. It just says digital wireless sensor.

Comment: "digital wireless sensor" is too generic. I guess if you really want to know what it is you're gonna have to get a ladder and take it down. Examine it front and back, or maybe even open the case. Look for manufacturer name, model number, etc.

Comment: Ask about it on Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the box on the right is a temperature sensor: [http://www.amazon.com/GE-WIRELESS-DIGITAL-OUTDOOR-THERMOMETER/dp/B001E6DVT6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001E6DVT6).

Comment: That looks like the one. Interesting that there are two temperature sensors right next to each other.

Comment: Don't underestimate the weather geeks.